# What is media-role with pw-play

Tags: pipewire, media

I notice that the pw-play command (pipewire play audio file) accepts a media-role parameter.  It's not clear what are the valid options for media role, and what impact does it have.  I've search the man pages and online docs, and there is little info.  Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

From the [official freedesktop documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/ApplicationProperties/#pa_prop_media_role):

> This property should contain a short string that describes the role of
> a media stream, where role is one of:
>
> - "video": for movie/video streams from media
> - "music": for music streams from media players
> - "game": for audio from games
> - "event": for event sounds (i.e. button clicks, ...)
> - "phone": for phone data (i.e. voip speech audio)
> - "animation": for animations (i.e. Flash)
> - "production": for audio production applications.
> - "a11y": accessibility applications (i.e. screen readers, ...) This is a property of the actual streamed data, not so much the
>   application. However usually it is still safe to simply set a
>   process-global environment variable.

So, it describes what "human" role the media has. This makes sense when you think about it: you want your desktop environment to be able to reduce the volume of video when you're having a phone call, for example. But you don't want to teach your audio system about every single video player and every single phone application out there.